# R : object not found

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset

so i'm trying to process a dataset([fertility_diagnosis](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Fertility)) which i got from UCI dataset repository.

```
data = read.csv('fertility_rate.csv', header = FALSE)

summary(data)
str(data)
> str(data)
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ V1 : num  -0.33 -0.33 -0.33 -0.33 -0.33 -0.33 -0.33 -0.33 1 1 ...
 $ V2 : num  0.69 0.94 0.5 0.75 0.67 0.67 0.67 1 0.64 0.61 ...
 $ V3 : int  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ V4 : int  1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ V5 : int  1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ V6 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 ...
 $ V7 : num  0.8 0.8 1 1 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.6 0.8 1 ...
 $ V8 : int  0 1 -1 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 ...
 $ V9 : num  0.88 0.31 0.5 0.38 0.5 0.5 0.44 0.38 0.25 0.25 ...
 $ V10: Factor w/ 2 levels "N","O": 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...

data[, c(V3:V6,V8)] <- sapply(data[, c(V3:V6,V8)], as.numeric)
> data[, c(V3:V6,V8)] <- sapply(data[, c(V3:V6,V8)], as.numeric)
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , c(V3:V6, V8)) : object 'V3' not found
```

one can see the variable names as V1-V10. where V3-V6 and V9 are int type.
so i'm trying to convert them to numeric type . 
but in the output i get object not found.

```
> head(data,5)
     V1   V2 V3 V4 V5 V6  V7 V8   V9 V10
1 -0.33 0.69  0  1  1  0 0.8  0 0.88   N
2 -0.33 0.94  1  0  1  0 0.8  1 0.31   O
3 -0.33 0.50  1  0  0  0 1.0 -1 0.50   N
4 -0.33 0.75  0  1  1  0 1.0 -1 0.38   N
5 -0.33 0.67  1  1  0  0 0.8 -1 0.50   O
```

and also i tried to apply regression to num type variables as below

```
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(data$V10, SplitRatio = 0.75)
train = subset(data, split == TRUE)
test = subset(data, split == FALSE)

lin_reg = lm(formula = V10 ~ V1+V2+V7+V9,
             data = train)
     > lin_reg = lm(formula = V10 ~ V1+V2+V7+V9,
       +              data = train)
   Warning messages:
    1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
      using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
    2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

can anyone help me to know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In R a vector of int type will behave as numeric for any function that requires numeric. And `is.numeric(.)` will return TRUE. There is no need to make the conversion. The error you reported came from not quoting the variable names.

Comment: but when i used head(data, 5) you can see there variable names V1,V2...V10 . and also i splitted the dataset into train and test using my target variable V10 . and also what about the error in regression function lm?

Comment: You can argue with me all you want but you must understand that R VARIABLES NAMES MUST BE QUOTED INSIDE THE j-ARGUMENT TO "[". Furthermore you cannot use range operators with variable names. R is not SAS. And having a response variable be a factor in `lm` makes no sense.

Comment: sorry sir i'm not arguing , it's just i never come across this type of error when i previously used datasets without variable names. according to my knowledge if use header=FALSE in read.csv() R will auto-assign variable names as V1,V2...  . here i'm trying to understand my mistakes and i'm not arguing. thank you for acknowledging .

Comment: Perhaps you have earlier been committing the horrible R sin of using the `attach` function?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think you made a simple mistake that you will be kicking yourself for. Your lm() model should use the syntax

```
lm(Response(dependent).variable~Predictor(Independent).variable)
```

I believe you are getting this error because your response variable is a factor variable not numeric. If you are sure that v10 is the response variable you want look into logistic regression (https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-a-logistic-regression-in-r/). However, what I suspect is that you want to know how one of your numeric variables changes in response to V10 and some other variables. Is this correct? I would need to know more about your variables and what you are trying to test to explain further.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Can you please correct the spalling of independent and dependent?

Comment: i'm trying to use both multiple linear regression and logistic regression. and i'm sorry for forgetting that linear regression cannot be applied against a factor variable whereas logistic regression is applied against a factor variable. thankyou for pointing out. but anyway i want to scale all the variables so when i tried scaling i get the object not found . i'm doing this to findout whether scaling let me to fine tune my algorithm accuracy

Comment: @42 bro your cranky... But yes my bad.

Comment: And to both of you ... Heads up ... it was not an "error", rather a warning. The factor was coerced to 1's and 2's and then the linear regression was run. To hareen: Your comment about scaling makes no sense to me. You need to post code and error messages.

Comment: Again my bad you are correct it was a warning not an error. Your attention to detail is unmatched. Although my point remains valid.

Comment: Hareen I suggest you do some googling and post a new question with the correct vernacular and syntax too demonstrate what you mean. We addressed the problem you show here. Best of luck.